# Javascript file load error after GET request

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a problem about including javascript files to html.

I have an index.html which runs index.js

```
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I also have viewer.html under view directory. And It has view.js

```
<script src="view.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In index.js there is a get request to view.html when a button clicked in index.html

```
function viewReport(){
    $.get('view/view.html', function(data) {
        $('#filediv').html(data);
    });
}
```

When I run `localhost/view/view.html` it works fine. But when I click the button and make get request, It give me that error. Seems like it tries to find view.js in root directory.

`http://localhost/view.js 404 (Not Found)`

How can I solve this problem without copy/move view.js to root directory?

Comment: Either put the path in view.html as `src="view/view.js"`, or use absolute paths.

Comment: by absolute path you mean, /var/www/html/view/view.js ?

Comment: No, the HTTP path of course. Either beginning with `http://...`, or beginning with `/...` to automatically address the domain root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a preceding slash, and closing your url string.

```
function viewReport(){
$.get('/view/view.html', function(data) {
    $('#filediv').html(data);
});
```

}